# Select a range of td cells with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have the following table

```
<table>
    <tr><td> #TD1 </td><td> #TD2 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> #TD3 </td><td> #TD4 </td></tr> 
    <tr><td> #TD5 </td><td> #TD6 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> #TD7 </td><td> #TD8 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> #TD9 </td><td> #TD10 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> #TD11 </td><td> #TD12 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> #TD13 </td><td> #TD14 </td></tr>
</table>
```

With jquery how do I select

1. #TD5, #TD7 and #TD9 ?
2. #TD6, #TD8 and #TD10 ?

I'm interested in an adaptable solution as my table might vary in columns and rows and I might need to select 4 rows going down rather than just three.

So far I've got

```
 $("table tr:gt(1) td:nth-child(1)").css('color','red')
```

but it doesnt stop at `#TD11`

See also http://jsfiddle.net/2ygJk/

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$("table tr:gt(1):lt(3)").css('color','red')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ygJk/4/

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Filter](http://jqapi.com/#p=filter) is your friend

```
var indexes = [5,7,9]; // the indexes you would like to filter out

var filterdCelles = $('td').filter(function(i){
    return indexes.indexOf(i) > -1;
})
```

And then you can just do:

```
filterdCelles.css('color','red'); // changes the font to this color
```

Comment: `filter` returns the element if the condition is `true`, `return indexes.indexOf(index) > -1`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. The trick is to select rows that are  *both* greater than one index *and* less than another index:

```
$("table tr:gt(1):lt(3) td:nth-child(1)").css('color','red'); // 5,7,9
$("table tr:gt(1):lt(3) td:nth-child(2)").css('color','blue'); // 6,8,10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/EaZsG/

Comment: That has got to be one of the ugliest selectors I have ever come across (no offence!) :P I would hate to see that in code that I'm working on....

Comment: @Lix Seems perfectly clear to me. Hope you don't have an equal aversion to regular expressions, because those are indispensable regardless of how "ugly" they are.

Comment: Naaa... regexes are are pretty ;) It is clear what the selector is trying to do - however when I come across complex selectors such as this one, I'll usually want to take a step back and rethink my logic or markup structure... Just my own preference for readability I guess..